# How do I set the icon for my jframe without having to put the icon on my desktop when exporting the jar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, embedded-resource, imageicon

I want to set the icon for my java game to an icon called lgico.png, but when I use:

```java
static ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("lgico.png");
public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
    frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
}
```

My jar file does not have the icon when I create it and put it on my desktop.

Here is my window class in it's entirety:

```java
package com.teto.main;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Window extends Canvas {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5486926782194361510L;
    static ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("lgico.png");
    Cursor csr = new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR);
    public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        frame.setCursor(csr);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

I've attempted to find solutions on this site multiple times only to be met with a NullPointerException and my program being a white screen with nothing on it.

I apologize if what I am trying to express doesn't seem very clear as my native language isn't English.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't extend Canvas. You are not adding functionality to the Canvas class so there is not reason to extend it.
2. Don't call your class Window. The is an AWT class with that name. Class names should be descriptive.
3. If you are using a jar file, then you probably need to load the image as a resource:

Here is a basic example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

class FrameIconFromMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame with icon");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                String imageName = "dukewavered.gif";
                URL imageUrl = f.getClass().getResource(imageName);

                if (imageUrl == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("imageUrl not found using default classloader!");
                    imageUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(imageName);
                }

                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( imageUrl );
                f.setIconImage( icon.getImage() );
                f.setSize(400,300);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
                f.setVisible( true );
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at com.teto.main.FrameInGame.<init>(FrameInGame.java:27)
 at com.teto.main.Game.<init>(Game.java:25)
 at com.teto.main.Game.main(Game.java:209)`

Comment: i might just be typing in the directory wrong or something idk

Comment: ok i fixed it but now i am getting the , "imageUrl not found using default classloader!" string in console, and I am not entirely sure on what exactly this means (i am new to java)

Comment: nvm i got it working, you dont know how happy you just made me, i have been attempting to make this work for a literal whole day